# Vbnet 2017, first head shoot on modbus

Tags: serial-port, modbus

i need help for reading a serial port with modbus protocol.
Told me for reading a HEX value from chipset, need to send before reading:

> 1E 03 00 0C 00 01 46 66  ..

The respond example is:

> 1E 03 02 xx yy ch cl

```
Imports System          'To Access Console.WriteLine()
Imports System.IO.Ports 'To Access the SerialPort Object
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine(ReceiveSerialData())
    Console.Read()
End Sub

Function ReceiveSerialData() As String
    'modbas
    ' Receive strings from a serial port.
    Dim returnStr As String = ""
    Dim com9 As IO.Ports.SerialPort = Nothing
    Try
        com9 = My.Computer.Ports.OpenSerialPort("COM9")
        com9.ReadTimeout = 5000
        com9.BaudRate = 19200
        com9.Parity = Parity.None
        com9.DataBits = 8
        com9.StopBits = StopBits.One
       ' com9.Write("1E 03 00 0C 00 01 46 66") ' stringa che serve per farsi rispondere dal chip, obbligo di inviarla
        ' com9.Read("1E 03 00 0C 00 01 46 66",0,8)
        Do
            Dim Incoming As String = com9.ReadLine()
            If Incoming Is Nothing Then
                Exit Do
            Else
                returnStr &= Incoming & vbCrLf
            End If
        Loop
    Catch ex As TimeoutException
        returnStr = "Error: Serial Port read timed out."
    Finally
        If com9 IsNot Nothing Then com9.Close()
    End Try
    Return returnStr
End Function

End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

If looks like you are using the Modbus RTU serial protocol.  If you are, you don't want to write a string, you want to write the raw bytes, something like:

```
byte[] request = new byte[]{1E,03,00,0C,00,01,46,66};
com9.Write(request, 0, request.Length);
```

You will also need to read the raw bytes.  Something like:

byte[] response = new byte[256];
com9.Read(response, 0, 7); // <- count (7) really depends on response packet

This is not the best way to read, you may get exception responses, etc. but it should work for a quick test.

Are you sure that your COM settings are correct?  By the standard you should always send 11 bits per byte so:

```
1) Even/Odd/Mark parity bit
9600/19200 BAUD
8 data bits
1 Stop Bit

OR

2) No parity bit
9600/19200 BAUD
8 data bits
2 Stop Bits <- an extra stop bit
```

Of course, some devices do support other combinations.